# Simple and fine for loop doesn't work

Tags: c#, for-loop

I feel stupid to ask this question but i got headache trying to find out why this simple for loop didn't work.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       for (int i = 1; i>=5; i++)

            label2.Text = "aaaa";
    }
```

Comment: How many times do you think it will loop using `i>=5;` ?

Comment: I have rolled back your edit - you cannot completely change the nature of a question once answers have been posted.  If you want to edit your post and add more info, thats fine, but a new question might be better.

Comment: for(variable `i` = 0; while variable `i` is less than 5; increment variable `i`)...  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)... No such question as a stupid question... although you may find that you learn a whole lot faster using a `Console application`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using a greater than sign, use the less than

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++)

        label2.Text = "aaaa";
}
```

Comment: i meant for (int i = 1; i==5; i++) not i>=5

Comment: what's the point of doing a loop at all if you're doing i==5?

Comment: `i == 5` equals: Loop if `1 == 5` which will never happen... What you want is to loop *unitl* `i == 5`. That will be: Loop while `i is less than 5`... Which is `ì < 5`. Since you're counting up from 1.

Answer (score 1):

first iteration: 1==5 which evaluates to false, so it will exit

You should read how the for loop works.
Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts. Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block), if it is true Statement 3 is executed after the loop (the code block) has been executed.
And this repeats until statement 2 becomes false

Comment: sorry i meant        for (int i = 1; i==5; i++) not i>=5

Comment: still same reason :)

Comment: isn't the condition where i hits that value (5) so it will exit?

Comment: if it's false anytime, it will stop. so 1 == 5, stop.   if you have int (i = 5; i==5; i++), it will run once